# Mapping a 2d Char list in Scala

Tags: scala

So I'm trying to recreate [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/4bc3el/20160321_challenge_259_easy_clarence_the_slow/d17v3ge) code with Scala. This is what I have so far:

```
/*
This is a program for the #259 [Easy] Clarence the Slow Typist /r/dailyprogrammer challenge
The algorithm was created by /u/derision.
*/
object Clarence {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val ip = args(0)
        println(ip.tail.zip(ip).map(_.map(x => "123456789.0".indexOf(x))))
    }
}
```

This should produce a 2d array, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
scala Clarence.scala 219.45.143.143                                                                                                                    
/home/mattjone/sw/coding/learning-scala/Clarence.scala:8: error: value productElements is not a member of (Char, Char)
        println(ip.tail.zip(ip).map(_.map(x => "123456789.0".indexOf(x))))
                                      ^
one error found
```

From what I can tell it's saying that you can't use .map on a array of characters, but that doesn't make sense. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that `map` is not a member of `(Char, Char)`, which is a **Tuple**, not an array.
If you extract `ip.tail.zip(ip)` into a `var`, you can see it's type is `Seq[(Char, Char)]`:

```
val zip: IndexedSeq[(Char, Char)] = ip.tail.zip(ip)
```

You can solve this by transforming each tuple into a sequence (with size 2), for example using `productIterator` (but there are other ways):

```
println(ip.tail.zip(ip).map(_.productIterator.toList.map(x => "123456789.0".indexOf(x))))
```

That would result in printing a 2D "array" (actually a `Vector` of `List`s).

Perhaps a more readable version would be one that prints a list of Tuples, and names each part of the tuple for clarity:

```
// this will be applied to each part of the tuple:
def transformChar(c: Char): Int = "123456789.0".indexOf(c)
// map each tuple to a new transformed tuple:
println(ip.tail.zip(ip).map { 
  case (prev, cur) => (transformChar(prev), transformChar(cur))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tzach Zohar answered you about why `map` don't worked.

My codes may be not relate to that issue, but if you want to create 2D Char list in Scala, how about this solution?

```
val x = "123456789.0".toList.sliding(2).map(_.reverse).toList
```

This code will transform from "12345..." to List(List(2, 1), List(3, 2), List(4, 3)...) (`List[List[Char]]`)

But if you want the list members to be `Tuple2`, you can use this code instead:

```
val x = "123456789.0".toList.sliding(2).map(x => (x.last, x.head)).toList
```

and it will generate List((2,1), (3,2), (4,3), ...) (`List[(Char, Char)]`).
Then you can just print it later :)